# when ssh is run with a server + command argument, what startup profile runs if any?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, scripts

I know `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are among the start-up scripts used when `ssh` is used to login to a server – i. e. using `ssh` with server argument. However, the scenario where I am just using `ssh` with a server+command argument does not seem to pick up the same start-up scripts.

Assume I have bash as default shell. If `.bashrc` exists, I know it is picked up in this scenario. But if `.bashrc` does not exist and no other personal profiles exist, what else runs?

Is there another global script that provides the environment variables?

Comment: For once, there's `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has more than you probably want to know about it, but it's a great concise resource:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Basically, when you ssh to a computer, you are not running a 'login' shell, so different files are sourced.  In short, if your default shell is /bin/bash (default on Ubuntu), you will be sourcing a `~/.bashrc` in your home directory.  Check the `FILES` section of the bash man page (`man bash`), near the end, for other files that come into play.

Also, make sure you are on the lookout in your `.bashrc` for lines that exit if not using an 'interactive' shell.  A good way to figure this stuff out is to put in prints in your `.bashrc` and keep experimenting until you figure it out.

Like this:

```
# ~/.bashrc:

echo "HERE I WAS!"

# Exit here unless an interactive session.
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

echo "HERE I AM!"
```

Comment: So if assuming there are no personal profiles involved, is there anything else that actually runs in this scenario? Do you know? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like @muru has a good answer here for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Without a command, SSH runs a login shell. For `bash`, that involves sourcing `.profile` (which, on Ubuntu, sources `.bashrc`) (and `/etc/profile`, which sources `/etc/bash.bashrc`). There are other files which could be sourced instead, such as `.bash_profile`, but a default Ubuntu setup has only `.profile`.

```
$ grep bashrc /etc/profile .profile
/etc/profile:    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
/etc/profile:    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
/etc/profile:      . /etc/bash.bashrc
.profile:    # include .bashrc if it exists
.profile:    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
.profile:   . "$HOME/.bashrc
```

When run with a command, SSH doesn't run a login shell, so, according to [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1) (section `INVOCATION`):

```
When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
reads  and  executes  commands  from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if
these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the  --norc  option.
The  --rcfile  file option will force bash to read and execute commands
from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.
```

However, with a command, `bash` is not being run interactively. Then why is `.bashrc` sourced? Again, from `man bash`:

```
Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input
connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell
daemon, usually rshd,  or  the  secure  shell  daemon  sshd.   If  bash
determines  it  is  being  run  in  this fashion, it reads and executes
commands from ~/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these  files  exist  and  are
readable.  It will not do this if invoked as sh.  The --norc option may
be used to inhibit this behavior, and the --rcfile option may  be  used
to  force  another file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd generally
invoke the shell with those options or allow them to be specified.
```

Other files could be read by SSH (from [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh.1), section `FILES`):

```
~/.ssh/rc
     Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in,
     just before the user's shell (or command) is started.  See the
     sshd(8) manual page for more information.
/etc/ssh/sshrc
     Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in,
     just before the user's shell (or command) is started.  See the
     sshd(8) manual page for more information.
```

For environment variables, (from `man ssh`, section `ENVIRONMENT`):

```
Additionally, ssh reads ~/.ssh/environment, and adds lines of the format
“VARNAME=value” to the environment if the file exists and users are
allowed to change their environment.  For more information, see the
PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).
```

The `pam_env` module is enabled for SSH:

```
$ grep pam_env /etc/pam.d/sshd 
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

Therefore, variables in `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment` are also set (and `/etc/default/locale`, since `envfile` is set). However, these files are not sourced the way `.profile` is, so you cannot use shell commands here.